# Finding words in an array using a binary search function in C?

Tags: c, binary-search

I'm trying to make a program that takes a inputted string (as a command line argument), and then prints out what verbs are in the string. The list of verbs are in an array in a separate header file. The program is currently finding the verbs, but its printing the same word multiple times. Here is my code:

```
#include "verbs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void binary_search(char *list_of_words, int size, char *target){
    int bottom= 0;
    int mid;
    int top = size - 1;

    while(bottom <= top){
        mid = (bottom + top)/2;
        if (strcmp(&list_of_words[mid], target) == 0){
            printf("%s found at location %d.\n", target, mid+1);
            break;
        }
        if (strcmp(&list_of_words[mid], target) == 1){
            top= mid - 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&list_of_words[mid], target) == -1){
            bottom= mid + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char *input;
    int i = 0;

    input = strtok (argv[1], " \"\n");
    while (input != NULL){
        for (i = 0; i < VERBS; i++){ //VERBS is defined in verbs.h as 637
            binary_search(verbs[i], VERBS, input);
        }
        input = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry is this homework? There was already a similar question asked here (posted only a couple of hours ago)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781105/binary-search-with-character-arrays/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay the code you posted has all sorts of things that are incorrect.

1. You do not need the inner for loop. In fact it is wrong to have that there as for each substring that you get from argv[1] you will be doing the search, so the inner loop is very wrong. Note that I am assuming that your input is just one string, and your job is to find verbs that are substrings of that. If you need to check everything in argv put a for loop outside the while. Either way, the loop configuration you have is incorrect.
2. Why do you have white space as a delimiter to strtok? Any string delimiter by white space will not be in argv[1]!! So white space should not be a delimeter there. You should have things like .- etc
3. You are changing the input delimiters of strtok. Don't do that.
4. You are using strcmp incorrectly (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)
5. Return out of the function on the base case.

Anyway, I fixed your program based on your question, and the phrasing of it (it is a little unclear if you are expecting only 1 input string or several, I assumed 1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DELIM ",.-+=*"

void binary_search(char *list_of_words[], int size, char *target){
    int bottom= 0;
    int mid;
    int top = size - 1;

    while(bottom <= top){
        mid = (bottom + top)/2;
        if (strcmp(list_of_words[mid], target) == 0){
            printf("%s found at location %d.\n", target, mid+1);
            return;
        } else if (strcmp(list_of_words[mid], target) > 0){
            top    = mid - 1;
        } else if (strcmp(list_of_words[mid], target) < 0){
            bottom = mid + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i = 1;
    char *input = strtok(argv[1], DELIM);

    char *verbs[5] = { "do", "make", "shit", "talk", "walk" };

    while (input != NULL) {   
        printf("looking at %s\n", input);
        binary_search(verbs, 5, input);
        input = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you expect several strings through argv change:

```
    while (input != NULL) {   
        printf("looking at %s\n", input);
        binary_search(verbs, 5, input);
        input = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }
```

to

```
    for (i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        input = strtok(argv[i], DELIM);
        while (input != NULL) {   
            printf("looking at %s\n", input);
            binary_search(verbs, 5, input);
            input = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I am still having trouble printing out the verbs using the binary search function. For ex. "walk and talk" should print "walk talk". The idea I have is to return the position of these verbs, but I'm not sure how implement it.

Comment: I changed binary_search into a int function, and I'm trying to return mid if a verb is found, but it's not quite working.